# Error: Cannot find module 'internal/linkedlist' in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

I have a script that runs fine when I run it in terminal with node, but using WebStorm I can't properly run it as it crashes on a dependency require line.

I've attempted to `npm install internal/linkedList`, I've also attempted to `npm cache clean` (as recommended in another post).

The full stack trace is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/linkedlist'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/harshagoli/Library/Preferences/WebStorm2017.2/javascript/nodejs/8.1.4/core-modules/timers.js:26:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Comment: It would help to see the source code or have a link to it. Otherwise there is no way for us to reproduce it.

Comment: what Node.js version do you use for running your app in webstorm? see https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running/issues/7 for some hints